# Can I Disable CTRL+ALT+ArrowKey key combination in favor of the Windows 10 Virtual Desktops?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I want to use virtual desktops in Windows 10, that are activated with <kbd>CTRL + WIN + ← / →</kbd> key combination.

Often I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> key instead that <kbd>WIN</kbd> one, and I change my desktop orientation. I use a laptop so this key combination is useless for me.

Is there a way to disable this key combination in order to do not have my desktop upside down when I press wrong keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the Intel HD Graphics suite then. Go to the Options tab in the control panel and uncheck "Enable Hotkeys"

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that it was related to intel graphics rather than windows itself...

Comment: I'm waiting the two minutes interval...